# Orphaned tag wikis showing up in question search results?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tag-wiki

It appears we have a some orphaned tag wiki's showing up whenever someone searches for "D&D" on [rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).  As you can imagine, that's a hot search topic.

Details are [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/what-are-these-search-results).

Comment: Tag wikis are posts, so this is probably an issue with not filtering out those posts in search results.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff has posted his answer at [the question on RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/what-are-these-search-results/543#543).

In a nutshell: "Fixed on next deploy."